# Kubernetes. How to make a deployment accessible from another deployment using <host>:<port>?

Tags: kubernetes, cloud

I have a python fastapi api deployed in kubernetes. It is running ok.
For that I use a configuration similar to the following:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myapi-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapi-deployment
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapi
      tier: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapi
        tier: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapi
          image: path_to_my_container_repo
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret


---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapi-service
  namespace: mynamespace
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapi
    tier: backend
  ports:
    - protocol: "TCP"
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
  type: ClusterIP

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: mynamespace-ingress-all
  annotations:
    ...
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:

  - host: somedomain
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: myapi-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

The requirements of the project evolved so I have to add redis there.
I already have everything working correctly on localhost but I am having some problems when trying to move that to kubernetes.

I can create a redis Deployment correctly using:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: mynamespace
  name: myapiredis-deployment
  labels:
    app: myapiredis-deployment
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 0
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapiredis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapiredis
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: myapiredis
          image: redis:7.0.6-alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
```

But of course the two Deployments can not see each other and I am getting an "Error 111 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused" error when fastapi tries to connect to redis.

I have been trying to configure the Service to add the new redis-deployment there but all the examples I have found in the internet use another type of Service (Nodeport, loadbalancer). I am not even sure that this could be made with my ClusterIP type.

How can I configure to make my redis Deployment visible to fastapi using < host>:< port>?

Comment: The Redis installation should have its own Service, and you need to change the application's configuration to use the Service name as a host name (maybe using an environment variable).  Other Kubernetes Pods will not generally be `localhost` (if you set this up in plain Docker first, in the same way other Docker containers aren't `localhost` either).

Comment: @Alfonso_MA Did above comment helped you to resolve the issue.

Comment: @FariyaRahmat yes It did. I already voted it up. I finally solved that creating a Service for the redis deployment. But I used kubernetes secrets instead of environment variable as David suggested.

Comment: I'll proceed to post that as an answer for greater visibility of the community.Please consider upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @David Maze suggested ,the Redis installation should have its own Service, and you need to change the application's configuration to use the Service name as a host name (maybe using an environment variable) other Kubernetes Pods will not generally be localhost.

Refer to this [link](https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/installing-upgrading/) for more information.

Comment: I personally solved it using Kubernetes secrets instead of environment variables